# How can I run PHPUnit with CakePHP tests with phpunit.xml?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I want to run a AllModelTest with phpunit command.
But when I try to run, there is nothing to test as a result.
Of course, there are many test codes.

```
$vendors/bin/phpunit --configuration app/Test/phpunit.xml
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Develop/web/app/Test/phpunit.xml




Time: 30 ms, Memory: 3.75Mb


No tests executed!
```

Also when I use a "Console/cake" command, it looks fine.

```
$ app/Console/cake test app AllModel --stderr

Welcome to CakePHP v2.5.8 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Develop/web/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

...
/app/Test/Case/Model/JanTest.php
```

I wrote the phpunit.xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="phpunit-bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    stopOnFailure="false">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">Test/Case/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

And the phpunit-bootstrap.php is like this.

```
<?php

$file = __DIR__.'/../../vendors/autoload.php';
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Install dependencies to run test suite.');
}
$autoload = require_once $file;
```

And the target test file "AllModelTest.php" is like this.

```
<?php

class AllModelTest extends CakeTestSuite {
    public static function suite() {
        $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All model tests');
        $suite->addTestDirectory(TESTS . 'Case/Model');
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

What should I do to run the test from phpunit command ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CakePHP 2.x please just follow the documentation - there is a built-in shell that does the testing for you, as CakePHP 2.x is NOT compatible to PHPUnit4.0, you need to stick to 3.7 via this shell and not try to invoke the tests manually.

The command **[as documented](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#run-tests-from-command-line)** is

```
cake test [...]
```

So from your app dir, to test app tests:

```
Console/cake test app
```

It will then show you a list of available tests.

Answer (score 0):

The path specified by `<directory suffix="Test.php">Test/Case/</directory>` is relative to the location of the `phpunit.xml` file.

Also note:

- PHPUnit 3.7 is no longer activeley maintained by the PHPUnit project
- Organizing test suites by subclassing `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` (which `CakeTestSuite` seems to be used for) is discouraged by the PHPUnit project for several years
- You are likely to run into issues if you use both `CakeTestSuite` to organize your tests and the `<testsuites>` / `<testsuite>` elements of PHPUnit's XML configuration file

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue, and sometimes the flexibility that `phpunit.xml` provides is useful and a valid use case. In both my case and the original question, we needed to add some simple bootstrap code.

After a lot of tinkering around, I discovered that if PHPUnit is running from a phar file by cake's design, it will also automatically look for a `phpunit.xml` file from the directory where you are running the tests.

For the command line, this is the `app` folder. So the file should be located at `app/phpunit.xml`.

For the web test runner, this is the `app/webroot` folder. So the file should be located at `app/webroot/phpunit.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with Cake 2, assuming you have a `phpunit.xml` file in your app's `Config` directory:

`Console/cake test app AllModel --configuration=Config/phpunit.xml`